# Entity Framework code first - update database in different project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have a test dbcontext which I use for integration tests, which have pending changes. It's in this project: app.WebApi.Integration

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using app.Web.Data;
using app.Web.Model.Entities;

namespace app.WebApi.Integration.Data
{
    public class IntegrationTestDbContext : DbContext, IDbContextFactory<IntegrationTestDbContext>
    {
        public IntegrationTestDbContext(string conn = "DefaultConnection")
            : base(conn)
        {
            Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        }

        public IntegrationTestDbContext() { }

        public virtual IDbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }
        public virtual IDbSet<Answer> Answers { get; set; }


        public virtual void MarkAs(object item, EntityState entityState)
        {
            Entry(item).State = entityState;
        }

        public IntegrationTestDbContext Create()
        {
            return new IntegrationTestDbContext();
        }
    }
}
```

But my migrations are in a seperate project: app.Web.Data. Does anyone know an ef command where I can update IntegrationTestDbContext with the migrations from the other project?

Comment: Did i undestand it correctly? The migrations history (migration files) in other project and you have 2 db contexts one for production and one for testing?

Comment: @BassamAlugili At the moment we have two separate db contexts which point to the same sql server db. One of these db contexts is used by our integration tests and it's in that project solely for that reason. If I try to update-migrations for the integration context it says that there are pending changes. I would like to know if it's possible to use the migration classes that are in another assembly.

Answer (score 1):

You need a custom DbMigrationsConfiguration :

```
namespace MyProgram.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Reflection;
    using MyProgram;

    internal sealed class MyConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyProgram.MyDbContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;

            // This is the assembly where your real migration are (Your DbContext not for test!)
            MigrationsAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            MigrationsNamespace = "AssemblyNamespace.Migrations";
        }
    }
}
```

After that you can create the migration from the code by using DbMigrator or use the NuGet console like that:

**Update-Database [-SourceMigration ] [-TargetMigration ] [-Script] [-Force] [-ProjectName ] [-StartUpProjectName ] [-ConfigurationTypeName ] [-ConnectionStringName ] []**

Update-Database will create and update the used database.

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration YourId -ProjectName MyProject -ConfigurationTypeName MyProject.Migrations.MyConfiguration
```

You can pass the connection string as parameter for the update-database command if the the startup project(app.config) does not contains the connection string

Answer (score -1):

This is the command what I use for .net core (.net 5)

```
dnx ef migrations add ClassLibraryMigration -c ClassLibraryContext -p ClassLibrary

dnx ef database update -c ClassLibaryContext
```

Comment: his question is not related to dot net core and in the dot net core release candate 2 dnx is obsolete.

Comment: The solution is in .net 4.6 so this answer won't work for me.